# Statistical test for recommendation algorithms

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, ranking, recommender-system

I've developed 2 different image based recommendation systems for an e-commerce company and now it's time to evaluate them using some statistical tests. Both algorithms work in a way in which if fed an image, they return the 5 most similar (ranked) images which are then recommended.

Assume Algorithm 1, if shown item $A$ and recommends (most similar first) $E,C,D,B,F$. Algorithm 2, if shown item $A$ recommends $E,C,B,F,G$.

**Questions:**

1. How can I compare which one of the above is the best? I don't have any "ground truth" to compare against.
2. How do I know that the algorithms are actually "working" and engaging customers more in the website?

I hope my questions are clear.

Comment: Your questions are clear and the answers even more so: You have to collect ground truth data to evaluate the recommenders formally and you have to do A/B testing to evaluate which algorithm leads to higher customer engagement.

Comment: @dipetkov - Hello and thanks for your answer. I get the A/B testing, but I'm wondering what you mean by collect ground truth data? What constitutes the ground truth? Am I supposed to rank the images myself and have that as ground truth? As I see it, the ground truth is subjective and does not really exist in terms of hard data. Or were you thinking about something else?

Comment: You have to algorithms and you want to know which one is better. You need an "arbiter" so that you can choose (subjective though the arbiter might be). If you only care about customer engagement you can skip the formal evaluation. In that case the customers are the arbiter.